# Is there a way to modify URL with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url

Normally .htaccess does it but I don't have access to file directories (on blogger)

What I am trying to do is to redirect

"*mysite.com/a/...*" to "*mysite.com/b/...*"

Just like in [9xbud](https://9xbuddy.com)

Is that possible or no without htaccess?

Comment: You want to use javascript to rewrite URL or simply redirect? For redirect you can use meta refresh. https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste this on your mysite.com/a/ location in "script" tag

```js
location.replace("mysite.com/b");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to redirect to a new URL

```
window.location.replace( "mysite.com/b/...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
window.location.href = "your.new.url/the/path/you/want/2/visit";
```

If you want to do it from a certain page, then you can do it like

```
if (window.location.href === "some.url/some/path") {
    window.location.href = "your.new.url/the/path/you/want/2/visit";
}
```